# requiring image in react-native 0.14.2

Tags: react-native

Doing this my code works fine

```
<Image
source={require('../../assets/images/music_star.png')}
style={styles.musicStar}
/>
```

But doing this gives me an error

```
let imgSource = '../../assets/images/music_star.png';
<Image
source={require(imgSource)}
style={styles.musicStar}
/>
```

I get an error:

Requiring unknown module "../../assets/images/music_star.png"

What am I doing wrong? How to require images stored in a variable in react-native 0.14.2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read more [in the docs](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/docs/Images.md) but basically, in order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically:

```js
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />

// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
```

To pass an image from parent to child, you should require it in the parent:

```js
/**
 * The entry point for the iOS app.
 */
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  Image,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Image source={this.props.image} />
    )
  }
}

export default class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Child image={require('./test.png')} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => Parent);
```

Comment: is there a way i can pass image static path from parent to child via props?